# Update field in model base on matching quantities in another with foreign key

Tags: python, django

I am trying to update a boolean field in my current model when two quantities in a second model, with a FK,  are equal.

this is a one to many relation, so I need to check that the two quantities are equal for every instance of the Foreign key.

I think what I am trying to do will work, but I am unsure of how to write it. I have only been working in Python/Django for a couple of weeks now

```
class ModelA():
  model_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  is_true = models.BooleanField(default=False)

  def update_is_true(self, *args, **kwargs):
    disting_model = ModelB.objects.filter(
      model_number=self.model_number
    )
    pod = self.modelb_set.all()

    ordered = sum([p.ordered for p in pod])
    received = sum([p.qty_received for p in pod])

    if received >= ordered:
        self.is_true = True
        self.save()

    """
    get a count for every instance of (ordered != received) 
    for each model_number. If count = 0, set (is_true = True) 
    """



class ModelB():
  model_number = models.ForeignKey(ModelA), on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  ordered = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  received = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Here is my db structure.

```
        ModelA
id     model_number     is_true
1      1                False

        ModelB
id      modelA_id      ordered     received
1       1                 15          15
2       1                 25          25
```

Comment: its better to use signals for the work you are trying to do

Comment: What is the question? If the code works, it works. This code has invalid syntax, since there's a dangling `if` clause. I recommend reading the docs about [reverse foreign key relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects). ModelA will have a `model_b_set` property that is the reverse of `ModelB.model_number`, so there's no need to do that filter.

Comment: If `is_true` is supposed to reflect the status of `ordered` and `received` at all times (i.e. you will never override it manually), I would make it a method (or property) and only turn it into a model field if there are performance issues.

Comment: I've updated my code, what I have above seems to be working the way I wan't it to. Now i just need to trigger the method.

Comment: What about just overload save in modelB and increment self.modelA ordered and received ?